# How to change permission of vmware's shared folder

Tags: permission-denied, chown, vmware-player

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 on vmware player. The shared folder is enabled and is visible on /mnt/fghs. But, the owner(root) can't be changed by chown. How to change it? Please, advice me.

Additionally, some person said the owner could be changed after modifying /etc/fstab. But, I couldn't find any information in /etc/fstab like  .host :/ /mnt/hgfs vmhgfs defaults 0 0. When I add the line into /etc/fstab file, wmware can't be start up.

Comment: It's resolved. I guess this issue is because of vmware tools version.

Answer (score 10):

probably a little bit late, but anyway.

Firstly, unmount your shared folder:

```
sudo umount /mnt/hgfs
```

then run:

```
vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/hgfs -o uid=1000 -o gid=1000 -o umask=0033
```

where you should consider change `uid` and `gid` to yours. Remember that:

```
id -u
id -g
```

will return your current user and group ID.

Take a look to `vmhgfs-fuse --help` for more options ;)

Comment: `vmhgfs-fuse .host:/vmware-share-folder-name /myMountLocation -o uid=1000 -o gid=1000` worked for me. Without umask, it just sets everything to 777 it seems.

Comment: as mentioned by @etech - parameter **umask=0033** defines access-permissions (in octal mode), mask specifies what is not permitted.

Comment: For me, additional parameter `-o allow_other` is needed to work correctly

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. Use `allow_other` option to grant access.

```
vmhgfs-fuse -o allow_other .host:/ /mnt/hgfs
```

see [unix.stackexchange.com: vmhgfs-fuse-permission-denied-issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310458/vmhgfs-fuse-permission-denied-issue)

Answer (score -1):

You can try [those steps](http://www.zendbox.de/2015/10/10/how-to-change-the-owner-on-a-shared-hgfs-folder/)

```
sudo su
touch /bin/remount_hgfs
chmod a+x /bin/remount_hgfs
echo '#!/bin/sh -e' >> /bin/remount_hgfs
echo 'umount /mnt/hgfs' >> /bin/remount_hgfs
echo 'mount /mnt/hgfs' >> /bin/remount_hgfs
echo '.host:/ /mnt/hgfs vmhgfs rw,ttl=1,uid=33,gid=33,nobootwait 0 0' >> /etc/fstab
line=`wc -l /etc/rc.local | cut -f1 -d' '`; sed -i "${line}ish /bin/remount_hgfs" /etc/rc.local
reboot
```